# Mordecai Richler essay - what's the grammar error?

Tags: grammar, errors

I was reading "Maple Leaf Culture Time", an essay by Mordecai Richler, and came across this page:

[image: page from Maple Leaf Culture Time]

Here is the text in question, transcribed:

> Neither is Mavis Gallant included among the more than 350 entries in
>   *Canadian Writers/Écrivains Canadiens*, a biographical dictionary edited
>   by Guy Sylvestre, Brandon Conron, and Carl F. Klinck, whilst my
>   listing manages a grammatical error and a new, yet provocative
>   judgement in one sentence. "In addition to his novels, Richler ...
>   worked on the film script for John Osborne's *Room at the Top*
>   and *Life at the Top*."

What's the grammatical error? The only blatant thing I could see what the minor plural mishap, wherein they mention two scripts but write "the film script." Is that it? or is he referring to something else?

Comment: In addition to the mysterious grammatical error, I see no judgement of any sort in the quote, let alone a "*provocative* judgment". Perhaps the sentence quoted in the previous paragraph was originally meant, as it says that five authors deserve mention (a judgement) but then only lists four (arguably a grammatical error), and the description was somehow misplaced. Or perhaps this is a reference to some unquoted part of the sentence in *Canadian Writers/Écrivains Canadiens*, which so offended the author that he couldn't even bring himself to include it in the essay.

Comment: @Azor-Ahai [Try reading the suggestions in this Meta post](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10395/cant-edit-to-change-code-format-to-quote-format). There are ways around the 6 character limit. You can also word it in a way that you're asking for an edit. It's current wording makes it sound like you're trying to make that an answer to the OP's question.

Comment: According to Wikipedia, [Mordecai Richler's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mordecai_Richler#Published_works) published works include *Life at the Top (1965)* (screenplay from novel by ***John Braine***). Your cited text could be considered "ambiguous" on that point, but if they didn't already kinow the authorship, most people would probably assume ***John Osborne's*** referred to both scripts, not just the first-mentioned.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that may be answer-worthy

Comment: @Hank: If OP thinks the ***script/scripts*** issue is a "minor mishap", I can't think how he would describe such a trivial point as the one I made (though I suppose if we want to get *really* anal, they could be seen as two faces of the same coin; perhaps Richler only published a *review* of *Life at the Top*, or there are some other "extenuating circumstances").

Comment: @FumbleFingers the reason I implied that the plural issue is a minor thing is because I found it rather odd that it Richler found it worth mentioning: Whilst it is an error, I was simply expecting an error that has less to do with a lack of attention (as the script/scripts issue is) and more to do with an improper understanding of grammatical rules. You may be right, however: the issue could be with the fact that they mean to have the possessive on **John Osborne's** be attached to both scripts, yet perhaps, despite it making sense to the readers, that could be incorrect grammatically.

Comment: @Devilius: Well, I only bothered to look up the authorship because I didn't think those two titles were part of a series (and thus similarly-named, as in *The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo / who Played with Fire / who Kicked the Hornet's Nest*). So I thought it was unlikely Osborne would have used both titles. But as to "provocative judgement" - who knows? Maybe your writer thinks or knows that Richler's only contribution to both films was to stagger around the set drunk every day, and he (the writer) thinks he's being daringly provocative by calling such activity "working" on the projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sentence

> In addition to his novels, Richler … worked on the film script(s) …

is meant to mean something along the lines of

- Richler wrote novels and worked on the film script(s) …
- Richler is known for his novels and the film script(s) … [which he worked on]

But, from a very pedantic point of view,
“In addition to his novels, Richler” is a compound subject,
so the sentence ‘actually’ means

> Richler’s novels … worked on the film script(s) …  
>   In addition, Richler … worked on the film script(s) …

in the sense of

> In addition to the other reindeer, Rudolph pulled Santa’s sleigh.

Obviously the intended meaning is clear.

---

I don’t see the “provocative judgment” either.

Comment: That's it! This makes a lot of sense. As for the provocative judgement, he's making a sarcastic joke: there is no provocative judgement, and in fact, it's an extremely sterile and purely factual entry.